# How do I stop wxFileDialog running on OSX from treating .itlp packages as files?

Tags: wxpython

I'm working on a program for which I need to be able to open a zip file containing an itlp (iTunes LP) and then do stuff to it.  I'm using wxFileDialog in wxPython for this purpose using the appropriate wildcard to only show zip files.

The problem is that because itlp's are folders not files they are still shown in the file dialog, but if you try to open them they're treated as files and the FileDialog returns the path as it would if it were a file instead of navigating into them like it would for a folder.      This may only happen on OSX, I've not tried it on any other platform, I've got vague recollections that Unix based OSs take file extensions more seriously than windows.

So my question here is what can I do to either hide the itlps in the file dialog, or get it to treat them like normal folders, not files?

Comment: "How do I stop wxFileDialog from treating files as files?"

Comment: an itlp is a folder containing a number of files, it does however have an extension i.e. .itlp .  This causes the problems described above.

Comment: I bet it is a file, you just don't know it.

Comment: In UNIX everything is a file.  But seriously, they're archive files that the OS allows you to browse transparently.  How to filter them out of `FileDialog` if the OS presents them as folders is a good question.

Comment: Thanks robots, my UNIX knowledge is sadly limited.  That's a much better phrasing of my question too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to open a file with a file dialog. wxPython wraps the native widgets where ever possible, so I'm guessing it's behaving the same way that the normal file dialog does. Try opening the file with a different program that loads that dialog and it'll probably behave the same way. On Windows when I need to open a zip file, I use a zip program or use the one built into Windows. File dialogs don't open them.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to make it clear in my original question, it's OSX that I have to get it to work on, the explanation was very helpful though and convinced me I should stick with my current solution which is just to check the selected file is ok after the path has been returned by wxFileDialog.  Cheers Mike